# How to convert property to it's name?

Tags: c#

Could anyone help me for this case:

```
public class MyClass
{

public int MyProperty{ get; set; }


  private void MyMethod()
  {
    // here I wat to get the name of MyProperty.
    // string name = "MyProperty"; <-- I don't want to hardcode it like this.
  } 
}
```

I don't want to hardcode it.
Is it posible?

Thnak you

Comment: You can get it through reflection. If your class has multiple properties, tag the relevant one with a custom attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use an expression tree:

```
var name = ExpressionTrees.GetPropertyName<MyClass, int>(x => x.MyProperty);

...


public static class ExpressionTrees
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TTarget>
         (Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> expression)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

(Alternative approaches can help with type inference, but I'm cutting to the chase here.)

If you rename `MyProperty`, then if you do it as a refactoring your usage in the call to `GetPropertyName` will also change, and if otherwise you'll get a compile-time failure.

There are numerous posts on Stack Overflow for how to extract the name from the expression tree, but it's worth being aware that this is still potentially flawed approach - there's nothing to stop you from writing:

```
ExpressionTrees.GetPropertyName<MyClass, int>(x => 0);
```

You can detect that at execution time, but not at compile time. There's also the matter of performance - it won't be *dreadful*, but it may not be *ideal*.

Depending on your requirements (in this case exactly why you want to identify that property rather than another one) then other approaches may work well, such as attributes.

Comment: +1. Expression trees are just cool... even if it is very unclear if OP want compile time safety of expression trees or just want name of a property of a class.

Comment: Thank you. Yup I usually use that expressionTrees class to get the name.

Comment: I just curious is there another simpler way to get property name without send the MyClass as a parameter, because I think we are in the class itself. Maybe what I want to ask is "Can the class itself know what is the name of it's property".

Comment: @dav: No, at the moment there's nothing like `typeof` for other members. Maybe one day...